# How can I use child_process to run a bash script that returns a list of values?

Tags: node.js, bash, child-process, execfile

How can I call the execFile method from child_process to run a bash script that returns a list of values?

My bash file (test.sh) returns a list of 8 values but the below script is printing only the last item of the list.

```
const { execFile } = require('child_process');
const child = execFile('./test.sh', (error,stdout,stderror) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

Comment: Return from bash as Json or custom format?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and it's working:

**test.sh input:**

```
echo "123"
echo "345"
echo "898"
```

**Output is:**

```
#node test.js 
123
345
898
```

So your code is working as expected. Perhaps your bash file make some errors or your output has some strange characters for example.